# How to migrate data from non-bdr pgsql to bdr pgsql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

I have fusionpbx with simple pgsql working ... Now i have created HA fusionpbx with bdr pgsql and it is working fine but I don't know how to migrate data from non-bdr pgsql to bdr pgsql ...

Answer (score 3):

pg_dump worked for me.

```
pg_dump $non_bdr_db > db.sql
psql $bdr_db < db.sql
```

Although if you have some fancy extensions (in my case it's PostGIS) you might want to restore the database from the backup first (separately on each and every node of your BDR cluster) and **then** enable the BDR extension.